# Green's Function for Dirichlet problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, greens-function, poissons-equation

I have been studying Green's functions for Laplace/Poisson's equation and have been having some trouble on a few things. In Strauss's book he claims the solution to the Dirichlet problem is: 
$$u(\bf x_0)= \iint_{bdy D} u(\bf{x})\frac{\partial G(\bf{x},\bf{x_0})}{\partial n} \,dS\label{1}\tag{1}$$ 
But in other texts I have seen it defined as 
$$u(x) = \int_\Omega G(x,\xi)\Delta u \,dy + \int_{\partial \Omega} u(y) \frac{\partial G(x,\xi)}{\partial n} \,dS\label{2}\tag{2}$$
I must be missing something here, but I cannot pinpoint what exactly. Which definition is the correct one? Are they equivalent? I suspect the first equation is assuming a homogenous PDE.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct, otherwise they are "equivalent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula \eqref{2} you give includes the solution to the Dirichlet problem for both equations, i.e. for Laplace's and Poisson's equations.

Precisely, the Dirichlet problem for Poisson's equation reads as
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u(x)=f(x) & x\in \Omega\\
u|_{\partial\Omega}=U(x) & x\in \partial\Omega
\end{cases},
$$
while the same problem for Laplace’s equation looks identical except for the fact that in this case $f\equiv0$.
If $f(x)\not\equiv 0$ then $\Delta u(x)\not\equiv 0$ and you have the proper Poisson's equation, thus
$$
\int_\Omega G(x,\xi)\Delta u \,dy\neq 0,
$$
and formula \eqref{2} holds in full. On the other hand, if $f(x)\equiv 0$ then $\Delta u(x)\equiv 0$ thus you have the proper Laplace's equation and 
$$
\int_\Omega G(x,\xi)\Delta u \,dy= 0,
$$
thus formula \eqref{2} reduces to formula \eqref{1}.

Comment: Thank you! So in that case, is using the Green's function method as simple as computing the integral, assuming the Green's function is known?

Comment: @WBSS yes, the true real difficulty is computing the Green ‘s function for a given domain. And as you may have guessed from \eqref{2},  the directional derivative of Green’s function for a given domain on its boundary is nothing less that the Poisson kernel for that domain. Thus the information provided by Green’s function is truly complete.

Comment: Ah I see, things are a lot clearer now! Thank you!